# JS: Получить содержимое тегов без отступов

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Всем привет!

У меня есть задача в том, что-бы заключить Markdown содержимое в div, который в последующем обрабатывается отдельно. Проблема в том, что в исходном документе каждый блок форматирован отступами, соответственно содержимое блока я тоже получаю с этими отступами:

```html
<div id="someblock">
      <div id="markdownBlock">
          #Markdown test
          * Test
      </div>
</div>
```

И при получении содержимого markdownBlock я получаю

```
              #Markdown test
              * Test
```

вместо

```
#Markdown test
* Test
```

Как можно получить содержимое блока без этих отступов?

Спасибо.

Comment: Написать функцию, которая будет удалять пробелы, табуляцию и т.д. Возможно, поможет простой метод `.trim()`

Comment: Проблема в том, что неизвестно сколько таких пробелов может быть, к тому-же они могут быть частью реального Markdown текста

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используем флаг `m` для регулярки что означает `multiline` - текст воспринимается как множество строк и позволяет для каждой из них использовать маркеры начала `^` и конца `$`, далее просто удаляем с начала каждой строки пробельные символы `^\s+`

```js
function getContext(){
  console.log(document.getElementById('markdownBlock')
    .textContent.replace(/^\s+/gm, ''))
}
```

```html
<div id="someblock">
      <div id="markdownBlock">
          #Markdown test
          * Test
      </div>
</div>
<button onclick="getContext()">Получить содержимое</button>
```

**Второй вариант решения**

Основан на нахождении и вычитании минимального отступа от левого края (но больше 2х символов - эмпирическая величина) задается в регулярке через `{minIndent}`, его можно получить и проще — из первой строки, но тут я вычисляю на основе всех строк, таким образом первая строка тоже может иметь отступ:

```js
// можно взять отступ первой строки за базу
function getFirstIndent(str){
  return str.match(/^\s+/).length || 0
} 

// можно найти минимальный из отступов среди всех
function getMinIndent(str){
  const minIndent = 2
  return Math.min(...str.match(/^\s+/gm)
    .filter(e => e.length > minIndent)
    .map(e => e.length))  
} 

function getContext(){
  const str = document.getElementById('markdownBlock').textContent
  const minIndent = getMinIndent(str)
  let rx = new RegExp( '^\\\s{' + minIndent + '}', 'gm')
  console.log(str.replace(rx, ''))
}
```

```html
<div id="someblock">
  <div id="markdownBlock">
       #Markdown test
      #Markdown test
        * Test
          - abc
  </div>
</div>
<button onclick="getContext()">Получить содержимое</button>
```

Comment: Проблема в том, что такой код только удалит пустые символы в начале каждой из строк, но, например, в Markdown отступ может быть сделан специально:

#Header\n
      \tSome tabbed text\n
Some text without tabs

А вариант с регуляркой сдвинет вторую строку максимально влево, что сломает форматирование

Comment: @Андрей дополнил ответ

Comment: Спасибо. Похоже, что это единственный рабочий вариант решить задачу